# Custom PFQuery and PFObject Connection in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I've created a Custom class for both `PFQuery` and `PFObject`, where I just Inherit/extend with those classes to not having to worry about importing Parse everywhere I use a Query or an Object.

However, I've encountered a problem when trying to mix `PFQuery` and `PFObject` together with their custom class.

Heres my Custom Classes which should in theory now have the same properties and effects as `PFObject` and `PFQuery`, which they do in most cases.

```
class CustomQuery: PFQuery {
    override init(className:String) {
        super.init(className: className)
    }
}

class CustomObject: PFQbject {
    override init(className:String) {
        super.init(className: className)
    }
}
```

But I've encountered a problem when trying to use a "..InBackgroundWithBlock" function from the Query. Here's the code:

```
func GetAsyncObjects(query:CustomQuery, closure: (dataObjects:[CustomObject]) -> ()) {
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(returnedObjects:[CustomObject]!, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        closure(dataObjects: returnedObjects!)
    }
}
```

The error occures at the second line of the block above, at "returnedObjects:[CustomObject]!" with the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '([CustomObject]!, NSError?) -> Void' to
>   expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayResultBlock?'

I literally can't find to see the solution for this. Obviously changing CustomObject there to `PFObject` would work, but that makes the whole point of my CustomObject and CustomQuery obsolete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the core issue here but your `CustomObject` subclasses from `PFQbject` (Notice there is a 'Q' instead of an 'O'). Also you will need to use `PFObject` in the closure inside of the `GetAsyncObjects` function because the signature of the block expects the returned objects to be of type `[PFObject]?`. You can circumvent the issue by doing something like this:

```
// in CustomQuery class
func GetAsyncObjects(closure: (dataObjects:[CustomObject]) -> ()) {
    self.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(returnedObjects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        // explicitly cast to your custom object
        closure(dataObjects: returnedObjects as! [CustomObject])
    }
}
```

So in order for the closure to get an array of `CustomObject`s back, you can just cast the `[PFObject]?` data you get back from Parse to your desired array type, in this case `[CustomObject]`.

Comment: It indeeds does the trick, but again the point of what I wanted was to avoid having the Import Parse statement anywhere else but my CustomQuery and CustomClass. Is this not possible due to the pre-defined signature that the block has? And If that Is the case, why wouldn't it? It's a PFObject just as much as the actually PFObject.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen If you put the `GetAsyncObjects` function into your custom query you wouldn't have to import it anywhere...

Comment: Excellent point. I can't believe I didn't think about that. You good sir, definitely deserve the accepted answer! Thanks!

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen Glad to have helped! Good luck with your project!

Comment: You can use `CustomObject` in the completion block of the query just fine since it's a subclass of `PFObject`. The error before was because it was a forced unwrapping instead of an optional `CustomObject`. This is totally fine: `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(returnedObjects:[CustomObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in`

Comment: @Russell I don't think that is correct. The `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` expects a `PFResultBlock` which is strongly typed to use `[PFObject]?` as the first parameter of its closure. Just because there is a `is-a` relationship between `PFObject` and `CustomObject` doesn't necessarily mean the signature will respect that.

Comment: @the_critic great catch! For some reason I could have sworn that I had used subclassed objects in a query result block, but after a quick check I'm totally wrong. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Russell It's always good to have somebody question others' statements, I could have been wrong too. Appreciate your input!